# Rider on Fedora 35 won't show netstandard

Tags: c#, .net-core, rider

### Problem description

I want to us source generators and therefore need a class library that targets netstandard2.0. Unfortunately I can't select it in the JetBrains Rider framework dropdown (see screenshot below).

### Environment details

Rider version: 2021.3.2 (Build: #RD-213.6461.51)

dotnet --info:

> .NET SDK (gemäß "global.json"):  Version:   6.0.100  Commit:
> 9e8b04bbff
>
> Laufzeitumgebung:  OS Name:     fedora  OS Version:  35  OS Platform:
> Linux  RID:         fedora.35-x64  Base Path:
> /usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/6.0.100/
>
> Host (useful for support):   Version: 6.0.0   Commit:  4822e3c3aa
>
> .NET SDKs installed:
> 3.1.118 [/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk]
> 5.0.206 [/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk]
> 6.0.100 [/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk]
>
> .NET runtimes installed:   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.18
> [/usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.9
> [/usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.0
> [/usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.18
> [/usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
> Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.9
> [/usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
> Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.0
> [/usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>
> To install additional .NET runtimes or SDKs:
> https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Framework selection in Rider:
[Framework dropdown greyed out and set to net6.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/724pk.png)

### Question

How can I get the framework-selection to let me select netstandard2.0 (and netstandard2.1)?

If you need any other info I'm more then willing to provide it.
Thanks in advance.

### Edit

After I have created a project with the preselected `net6.0` framework selection my `csproj` looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

I can manually change the `<TargetFramework>` value and everything works (`<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>`), but I just find it strange that I can't use the dropdown in project creation directly.

Comment: If you open the project file (*.csproj) in a text editor, what do you see? Edit the question to include that, so others might be able to help.

Comment: I just edited the question, hope this is the info you ment, @LexLi

Comment: Then you probably should report to JetBrains as a bug and see if they would like to change that. .NET Standard is going away as .NET 6 unifies all platforms together.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will talk to JetBrains then, just wanted to make sure that it wasn't a silly mistake on my end first. Will update this when I have a response from JetBrains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bug that has been reported to JetBrains team already: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-70004

As a workaround, following can be done:

- Right click on the solution and select Manage .NET SDK
- Select older SDK (e.g. 3.1) and latestMinor as Roll-forward policy
- Create new project for older framework
- Open Manage .NET SDK and set Roll-forward policy to the state it was before